# Can I include a header file into a new header file?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Can I include a header file into a new header file that I created? I put `#include <MCP23S17.h>`. I want to create a another header file.

Comment: > Can I include a header file into a new header file that I created? Yeah. That's what they are meant to be used.

Comment: Just remember to put [Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid problems... And remember to accept the most useful answer to avoid being bumped to the homepage uselessly...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just include both in the final program?

Happens all the time.

DHT.h needs AdaFruit_Sensor.h, for instance, so you just include both.

First AdaFruit
then DHT

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a header can include another header.  But if you are using the Arduino IDE and the headers aren't in the same folder, then you'll also need an #include line for it in the .ino file.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just try it to begin with instead of asking and waiting?

Comment: i want to llink MCP23S17.h file to my own created header file

Comment: can you give some suggestion to it

Comment: Suggestion to what?

Comment: Since Arduino IDE 1.6.6 it's no longer necessary to add includes to the sketch for library-library dependencies.